# Obtener nombre y versión del navegador usando Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero escribir algunas funciones que sean multinavegador y para ello necesito conocer mediante una función el nombre y la versión actual del navegador en el cliente, ¿cuál sería la mejor manera de hacerlo en Javascript puro?

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791) hay un snippet para eso. Básicamente debes analizar la cabecera `useragent`.

Comment: ¡Qué maravilla @Guz! Sugiero que lo pongas como respuesta para que lo tengamos también en castellano.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lo más exacto es analizar la cabecera `UserAgent`; la cual contiene datos como el navegador, la versión y el sistema operativo.

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918791) el usuario hace uso de expresiones regulares para obtener el navegador y la versión:

```js
var getBrowserInfo = function() {
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
};

console.log(getBrowserInfo());
```

Otra opción es usar el paquete [bowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bowser):

```js
console.log(bowser.name, bowser.version);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bowser/1.9.4/bowser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: La respuesta del enlace necesita corregirse para detectar "Microsoft Edge", esta es la corrección : [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser/69745466#69745466)

Answer (score 7):

```js
var txt = "";
txt += "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>";
txt += "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt += "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

la primer respuesta todavía es correcta, pero para Edge hay que cambiar `Edge` por `Edg`:

```
var getBrowserInfo = function() {
     var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
     M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
         tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edg)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
};
```

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, de esta forma ya puede detectar también el navegador "Microsoft Edge"