# Detectar el navegador con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero detectar el navegador que se esta usando para cambiar los estilos al header porque en firefox no es compatible(backdropfilter); Quiero saber como detectar que navegador se esta usando

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: `var nameNavigator = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

if(nameNavigator){
    document.getElementById('header').style.backgroundColor = '#000';
}`

Comment: Me funciona pero quisiera saber si hay otra manera mas corta

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener nombre y versión del navegador usando Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100922/obtener-nombre-y-versi%c3%b3n-del-navegador-usando-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Con Js puedes hacer uso de

```
navigator.userAgent
```

o de

```
navigator.appVersion
```